# Determine size of character array in C

Tags: c, pointers, arrays

I am trying to write a program that will talk to a XBee Pro S2B over serial from a PIC16 and I have some odd memory stuff going on...

I am a bit weak when it comes to pointers in C so I have been writing a test program using GCC to get it to work before I move it over to the PIC microcontroller. The biggest thing to note with the PIC is the memory constraints. So for this I would like to avoid adding any external libraries unless I absolutely have to (and avoid having to use malloc/free).

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

void printPacketArray(unsigned char *packetArray, int packetSize){
printf("OUTPUT PACKET: ");
for(int i = 0; i < packetSize; i++){
    printf("%02X ", packetArray[i]);
}
printf("\n");
}

/**
 * This function builds all of the frames to be wrapped into a packet
 */
int buildFrame(
unsigned char frameType,
unsigned char requestResponse,
unsigned char *destinationAddress64Bit,
unsigned char *destinationAddress16Bit,
unsigned char *rfPacketData,
int destinationAddress64BitSize,
int destinationAddress16BitSize,
int rfDataSize,
unsigned char **frameArray,
int **frameArraySize){
//  printf("Entering buildFrame\n");
//                      FT  RESP (Optional Dest Addr x64)    + (Optional Dest Addr x16)      Packet
int outputPacketSize = (1 + 1  + destinationAddress64BitSize + destinationAddress16BitSize + rfDataSize);
//  printf("Packet Size: %d\n", outputPacketSize);
unsigned char outputPacketArray[outputPacketSize];

// Add the frame type
outputPacketArray[0] = frameType;
//  printf("Frame type: %02X\n", frameType);

// Request response
outputPacketArray[1] = requestResponse;
//  printf("Response: %02X\n", requestResponse);

int arrayCount = 2;
// Add the destination address (64 bit)
if(destinationAddress64Bit != 0x00){
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        outputPacketArray[arrayCount] = destinationAddress64Bit[i];
//          printf("outputPacketArray[%d] = %02X\n", arrayCount, destinationAddress64Bit[i]);
        arrayCount++;
    }
}

// Ad the destination address (16 bit)
if(destinationAddress16Bit != 0x00){
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        outputPacketArray[arrayCount] = destinationAddress16Bit[i];
//          printf("outputPacketArray[%d] = %02X\n", arrayCount, destinationAddress16Bit[i]);
        arrayCount++;
    }
}

// Add the packet data
for(int i = 0; i < rfDataSize; i++){
    outputPacketArray[arrayCount] = rfPacketData[i];
//      printf("outputPacketArray[%d] = %02X\n", arrayCount, rfPacketData[i]);
    arrayCount++;
}

*frameArray = outputPacketArray;
//  printf("*frameArray = %p\n", outputPacketArray);

*frameArraySize = &outputPacketSize;
//  printf("*frameArraySize = %p\n", &outputPacketSize);

//  printf("Packet: ");
//  for(int i = 0; i < outputPacketSize; i++){
//      printf("%02X ", outputPacketArray[i]);
//  }
//  printf("\n");

//  printf("Exiting buildFrame\n");

return TRUE;
}


/**
 * This function wraps the frame data into the packet.
 */
int buildPacket(
unsigned char *frameData,
int frameDataSize,
unsigned char **packetArrayPtr,
int **packetArraySizePtr){
//                      7E  MSB LSB Packet          Checksum
int outputPacketSize = (1 + 1 + 1 + frameDataSize + 1);
int checksum = 0;
unsigned char outputPacketArray[outputPacketSize];

// Add the start delimiter
outputPacketArray[0] = 0x7E;

// Add the MSB (should always be 0x00)
outputPacketArray[1] = 0x00;

// Add the LSB (size of frameData)
outputPacketArray[2] = frameDataSize;

// Add the frame data
int arrayCount = 3;
for(int i = 0; i < frameDataSize; i++){
//        printf("CNT: %d\n", arrayCount);
    outputPacketArray[arrayCount] = frameData[i];
    checksum += frameData[i];
    arrayCount++;
}

// Add the checksum
outputPacketArray[arrayCount] = (0xFF - (checksum & 0xFF));
//    printf("CNT: %d\n", arrayCount);

//  printf("Packet: ");
//  for(int i = 0; i < outputPacketSize; i++){
//      printf("%02X ", outputPacketArray[i]);
//  }
//  printf("\n");

*packetArrayPtr = outputPacketArray;
*packetArraySizePtr = &outputPacketSize;

return TRUE;
}

int sendAPICommand(unsigned char* inputFrameData, int inputFrameDataLength){
unsigned char destinationAddress64Bit[] = {0x00, 0x13, 0xA2, 0x00, 0x40, 0x9C, 0x26, 0xE1};
unsigned char destinationAddress16Bit[] = {0xFF, 0xFE};
unsigned char *frameArrayPtr = 0x00;
int *frameArraySizePtr = 0x00;

//    printf("COMPARE:       7E 00 13 10 01 00 13 A2 00 40 9C 26 E1 FF FE 00 00 01 02 03 04 05 4A\n");
// We need to add in the radius and options before the data
unsigned char frameData[(inputFrameDataLength + 2)];
frameData[0] = 0x00; // Radius
frameData[1] = 0x00; // Options
for(int i = 0; i < inputFrameDataLength; i++){
    frameData[(i + 2)] = inputFrameData[i];
}

if(buildFrame(0x10, 0x01, destinationAddress64Bit, destinationAddress16Bit, frameData, 8, 2, (inputFrameDataLength + 2), &frameArrayPtr, &frameArraySizePtr) == TRUE){
    printf("COMPARE:       10 01 00 13 A2 00 40 9C 26 E1 FF FE 00 00 01 02 03 04 05\n");
    printPacketArray(frameArrayPtr, *frameArraySizePtr);
    // The building of the frame was a success
    if(buildPacket(frameArrayPtr, *frameArraySizePtr, &frameArrayPtr, &frameArraySizePtr) == TRUE){
        printf("COMPARE:       7E 00 13 10 01 00 13 A2 00 40 9C 26 E1 FF FE 00 00 01 02 03 04 05 4A\n");
        printPacketArray(frameArrayPtr, *frameArraySizePtr);

        return TRUE;
    }
}

return FALSE;
}

int main(){
unsigned char packetData[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05};

sendAPICommand(packetData, 5);

return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I cannot seem to find out why the results are not consistent. Using the Eclipse debugger, I get the following error:

```
frameData.15    Error: Multiple errors reported.\ Failed to execute MI command: -var-create - * frameData.15 Error message from debugger back end: mi_cmd_var_create: unable to create variable object\ Failed to execute MI command: -var-create - * frameData.15 Error message from debugger back end: mi_cmd_var_create: unable to create variable object\ Failed to execute MI command: -data-evaluate-expression frameData.15 Error message from debugger back end: No symbol "frameData" in current context.\ Failed to execute MI command: -var-create - * frameData.15 Error message from debugger back end: mi_cmd_var_create: unable to create variable object\ Unable to create variable object
```

on this line of code:

```
if(buildFrame(0x10, 0x01, destinationAddress64Bit, destinationAddress16Bit, frameData, 8, 2, (inputFrameDataLength + 2), &frameArrayPtr, &frameArraySizePtr) == TRUE){
```

When I run the program completely (it silently fails) and this is my text output:

```
COMPARE:       10 01 00 13 A2 00 40 9C 26 E1 FF FE 00 00 01 02 03 04 05
OUTPUT PACKET: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 D8 8C 28 03 01 00 00 00 B0 8A 97 5C FF 7F 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 8A 97 5C 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 30 00 00 00 90 8A 97 5C FF 7F 00 00 90 89 97 5C FF 7F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

I suspect the problem is I have a bad pointer (or pointers) in returning the size or the pointer to the character array but I don't know that for sure (or know how to get the program to fail in a way I can determine it).

Comment: Try debugging with [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) and compiling with [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (i.e. `gcc -Wall -g`) *without* using Eclipse. Consider also using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Why do you want to avoid `malloc` & `free` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `buildFrame`:

```
unsigned char outputPacketArray[outputPacketSize];
```

`outputPacketArray` is a local variable. Its lifetime ends when you leave the function. However you assign a pointer to it to an output parameter of the function:

```
*frameArray = outputPacketArray;
```

(Same for `outputPacketSize`)

These pointers do not point to valid memory anymore when you leave the function. You need to dynamically allocate the array:

```
unsigned char* outputPacketArray = malloc(outputPacketSize);
```

and then free it later. Alternatively you could provide an appropriately sized array to the function, but then you would need to calculate the size already in `main`.

For the size you don't need a pointer to pointer at all, just return it from the function, or use a simple pointer (instead of double pointer) as output parameter.